# Android 5 cannot connect to Raspberry Pi 3 acting as BLE Peripheral

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have made my own app to try to connect to a Raspberry Pi 3 that is advertising itself as a Bluetooth LE Peripheral. I know there is nothing wrong with the PI as I can connect to it fine with an iOS Application. **The Raspberry Pi device is not shown in the list.**

So I checked out [Google's code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt) (and their [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)) and I have been modding it to try just discover the device:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class DeviceScanActivity extends ListActivity {
    private LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private boolean mScanning;
    private Handler mHandler;

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 2;
    // Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_devices);
        mHandler = new Handler();

        // Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device.  Then you can
        // selectively disable BLE-related features.
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

        // Initializes a Bluetooth adapter.  For API level 18 and above, get a reference to
        // BluetoothAdapter through BluetoothManager.
        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        // Checks if Bluetooth is supported on the device.
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        if (!mScanning) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stop).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(null);
        } else {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stop).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(
                    R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_scan:
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
                scanLeDevice(true);
                break;
            case R.id.menu_stop:
                scanLeDevice(false);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Ensures Bluetooth is enabled on the device.  If Bluetooth is not currently enabled,
        // fire an intent to display a dialog asking the user to grant permission to enable it.
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
        }

        // Initializes list view adapter.
        mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter();
        setListAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);
        scanLeDevice(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // User chose not to enable Bluetooth.
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION:{
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    scanLeDevice(true);
                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        scanLeDevice(false);
        mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        final BluetoothDevice device = mLeDeviceListAdapter.getDevice(position);
        if (device == null) return;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, DeviceControlActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
        intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS, device.getAddress());
        if (mScanning) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            mScanning = false;
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public boolean checkForPermission(String permission) {
        if (permission == null) return false;
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{permission}, getCodeForPermissionRequest(permission));

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private int getCodeForPermissionRequest(String permission) {
        if (permission.equals(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) return REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION;
        return 0;
    }

    private void startScan() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan(mLeScannerCallback);
        } else {
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
    }

    private void stopScan() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().stopScan(mLeScannerCallback);
        } else {
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
    }

    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (!checkForPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) return;
        if (enable) {
            // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mScanning = false;
                    stopScan();
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);

            mScanning = true;
            startScan();
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            stopScan();
        }
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    // Adapter for holding devices found through scanning.
    private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mLeDevices;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public LeDeviceListAdapter() {
            super();
            mLeDevices = new ArrayList<>();
            mInflater = DeviceScanActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
        }

        public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
            if(!mLeDevices.contains(device)) {
                mLeDevices.add(device);
            }
        }

        public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {
            return mLeDevices.get(position);
        }

        public void clear() {
            mLeDevices.clear();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mLeDevices.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return mLeDevices.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            // General ListView optimization code.
            if (view == null) {
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
                viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(i);
            final String deviceName = device.getName();
            if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0)
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);
            else
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(R.string.unknown_device);
            viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());

            return view;
        }
    }

    // Device scan callback.
    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                    mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    };

    private android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback mLeScannerCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, final ScanResult result) {
            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(result.getDevice());
                    mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    };

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView deviceName;
        TextView deviceAddress;
    }
}
```

My Gradle file is as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1"
}

// The sample build uses multiple directories to
// keep boilerplate and common code separate from
// the main sample code.
List<String> dirs = [
    'main',     // main sample code; look here for the interesting stuff.
    'common',   // components that are reused by multiple samples
    'template'] // boilerplate code that is generated by the sample template process

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            dirs.each { dir ->
                java.srcDirs "src/${dir}/java"
                res.srcDirs "src/${dir}/res"
            }
        }
        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
        androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']

    }

}
```

And my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 Copyright 2013 The Android Open Source Project

 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->



<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <!-- Min/target SDK versions (<uses-sdk>) managed by build.gradle -->

    <!-- Declare this required feature if you want to make the app available to BLE-capable
    devices only.  If you want to make your app available to devices that don't support BLE,
    you should omit this in the manifest.  Instead, determine BLE capability by using
    PackageManager.hasSystemFeature(FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE) -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <activity android:name=".DeviceScanActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DeviceControlActivity"/>
        <service android:name=".BluetoothLeService" android:enabled="true"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: so you can't see the avilable bluetooth, or what?

Comment: The device is not even connecting - it does not appear in the list - have updated the question

Comment: Is it showing up in the Bluetooth system settings menu?

Comment: No it doesn't show up. What is weird is this code was working on old build tools version 23.0.2, but android won't let me roll back

Comment: i think your `scanLeDevice()` not completed yet, you sure that code worked before ?

Comment: @ Ibrahim Ali: It does find other devices, just not the pi. Currently only the iPhone can connect to the pi (I did disconnect the iPhone before testing)

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon then i will ask another simple Quest, how do you search for blueetooth devices on android? please open bluetooth device manager on the physical device and see if your pi already there in "available devices"

Comment: No it doesn't appear there either. Does that mean there is something wrong with my phone's hardware?

Comment: maybe, and maybe a problem with your pi code too.

Comment: Yeah but my iPhone code connects fine. Also the Android device picks up other BLE devices. My concern is that Google has updated the core libraries and now the y don't work. This seems to be confirmed here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt/issues - so unless someone is running BLE on SDK 25 I think it's actually a library problem

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon While you can't see pi bluetooth in real device bluetooth from the main bluetooth app, so we deprecate our app, and we have to cases, also just one case.. the pi code.